# Tomcat Session not run

Tags: java, spring, session, tomcat, spring-security

I have various Java programs developed with spring on some ubuntu server.
All server are at version 14.04, I use Tomcat7 and the server packages are continuously updated.

Since few week I have a strange problem:
when a user try to login in the program, apparently nothing happens, the program NOT gives error and asks you to enter your credentials again, and again..and again..

To unlock the access I have to access at tomcat manager, invalidating all created sessions so far (all attempts to login the session is successfully created). Once you clear the sessions, logins are successful.

Has anyone had the same problem? How can I fix the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

the best way to deploy: 1 tomcat >>> 1 application;

1. bin/shutdown.sh
2. replace application(war or folder)
3. bin/start.sh